# How to ensure dates are consistent in Python

Tags: python

I am iterating over some date strings that are formatted 2 different ways, and I want to ensure they are formatted the same, and are a datetime object.
The strings I have are like this:

```
#
'2020-10-25'
'25/10/2020'
#
```

So they are YYYY-MM-DD and DD/MM/YYYY
I want all dates to be formatted like DD/MM/YYYY

My current code looks like this:

```
for completedDate in dates:
    try:
        completeDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(completeDate, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    except:
        completeDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(completeDate, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
    print(completeDate)
```

Which outputs:

```
25/10/2020
2020-10-25
```

I want:

```
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
```

It seems to be working for the dates with dashes (YYYY-MM-DD) but doing the opposite for the slashes... I think it is probably something little but I've been staring at this too long, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should format your string same way in both scenarios

```
for completedDate in dates:
    try:
        completeDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(completeDate, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    except:
        completeDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(completeDate, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    print(completeDate)
```

With this code if data format is something else, like "25.10.2020", you'll get exception. That's probably something you want.

Comment: Perfect that did it, thanks! 
However when I perform `print(type(completedDate))` it returns `<class 'str'>` I have tried to add `.date()` on the end but it throws `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'` any ideas how to convert to date?

Comment: `completeDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(completeDate, "%Y-%m-%d")` returns DateTime object. It has strftime method to convert it to string. So don't call that strftime method and you'll have DateTime object.